# Creating a bookingsystem in in c++

Tags: c++

### I have these six files:

---

### Reservation.hpp;

```
#ifndef RESERVATION_HPP
#define RESERVATION_HPP

#include <string>
#include "Date.hpp"

class Reservation
{
    std::string referenceID;
    Date startDate;
    Date endDate;

public:

    Reservation(const std::string& referenceID, const Date& start, const Date& end);

    Reservation(const Reservation& other);
    Reservation& operator=(const Reservation& other);

    bool operator==(const Reservation& other) const;
    bool operator!=(const Reservation& other) const;

    bool Overlaps(const Reservation& other) const;

    const std::string& GetReferenceID() const;
    const Date& GetStartDate() const;
    const Date& GetEndDate() const;
};

#endif // RESERVATION_HPP
```

### Reservation.cpp;

```
#include "Reservation.hpp"
#include <stdexcept>


Reservation::Reservation(const std::string& referenceID, const Date& start, const Date& end)
{
    this->referenceID = referenceID;
    this->startDate = start;
    this->endDate = end;

    if (startDate > endDate)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalidate date values");
    }


}

Reservation::Reservation(const Reservation& other)
{


    this->referenceID = other.referenceID;
    this->startDate = other.startDate;
    this->endDate = other.endDate;

}

Reservation& Reservation::operator=(const Reservation& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {


        this->endDate = other.endDate;
        this->startDate = other.startDate;
        this->referenceID = other.referenceID;
    }

    return *this;
}

bool Reservation::operator==(const Reservation& other) const
{
    if (this->referenceID == other.referenceID && this->endDate == other.endDate && this->startDate == other.startDate)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool Reservation::operator!=(const Reservation& other) const
{
    if (this->referenceID != other.referenceID || this->endDate != other.endDate || this->startDate != other.startDate)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool Reservation::Overlaps(const Reservation& other) const
{
    if (startDate>endDate)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (this->referenceID == other.referenceID)
    {
        if (startDate >= endDate)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

const std::string& Reservation::GetReferenceID() const
{
    return this->referenceID;
}

const Date& Reservation::GetStartDate() const
{
    return this->startDate;
}

const Date& Reservation::GetEndDate() const
{
    return this->endDate;
}
```

### BookingSystem.hpp

```
#ifndef BOOKING_SYSTEM_HPP
#define BOOKING_SYSTEM_HPP

#include "Reservation.hpp"

class BookingSystem
{
    int capacity;
    int reservationCount;
    Reservation** reservations;

    void Expand();

public:

    BookingSystem(int capacity);
    ~BookingSystem();

    BookingSystem(const BookingSystem& other);
    BookingSystem& operator=(const BookingSystem& other);

    bool Reserve(const std::string& referenceID, const Date& start, const Date& end); 

    
    int GetReservationCount() const;
    int GetReservationCapacity() const;
    Reservation** GetReservations() const;
};

#endif // BOOKING_SYSTEM_HPP
```

### BookingSystem.cpp

```
#include "BookingSystem.hpp"


void BookingSystem::Expand()
{
    this->capacity += 10;
    Reservation** temp = new Reservation * [this-> capacity] {nullptr};
    for (int i = 0; i < reservationCount; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = this->reservations[i];
    }
    delete[]this->reservations;
    this->reservations = temp;
}



BookingSystem::BookingSystem(int capacity)
    :reservationCount(0), capacity(capacity)
{
    this->reservations = new Reservation * [this->capacity] {nullptr};
}

BookingSystem::~BookingSystem()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->reservationCount; i++)
    {
        delete this->reservations;
    }
    delete[]this->reservations;
}

BookingSystem::BookingSystem(const BookingSystem& other)
{
    this->capacity = other.capacity;
    this->reservationCount = other.reservationCount;

    this->reservations = new Reservation * [other.capacity] {nullptr };
    for (int i = 0; i < reservationCount; i++)
    {
        this->reservations[i] = new Reservation(*other.reservations[i]);
    }
}

BookingSystem& BookingSystem::operator=(const BookingSystem& other)
{
    if (this != &other)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->reservationCount; i++)
        {
            delete this->reservations[i];

        }
        delete[]this->reservations;

        this->capacity = other.capacity;
        this->reservationCount = other.reservationCount;
        this->reservations = new Reservation * [other.reservationCount] {nullptr };
        for (int i = 0; i < reservationCount; i++)
        {
            this->reservations[i] = new Reservation(*other.reservations[i]);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

bool BookingSystem::Reserve(const std::string& referenceID, const Date& start, const Date& end)
{
    if (this->reservationCount == this->capacity)
    {
        Expand();
    }
    Reservation temp(referenceID, start, end);

    for (int i = 0; i < reservationCount; i++)
    {
        if (this->reservations[i]->Overlaps(temp))
        {
            this->reservations[this->reservationCount] = new Reservation(referenceID, start, end);
        }
    }
    reservationCount++;
    return false;
}

int BookingSystem::GetReservationCount() const
{
    return this->reservationCount;
}

int BookingSystem::GetReservationCapacity() const
{
    return this->capacity;
}

Reservation** BookingSystem::GetReservations() const
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

### Date.hpp

```
#ifndef DATE_HPP
#define DATE_HPP

#include <string>

class Date
{
public:

    Date();
    Date(unsigned int day, unsigned int month, unsigned int year);
    Date(const Date& other);
    Date& operator=(const Date& other);

    bool operator==(const Date& other) const;
    bool operator!=(const Date& other) const;

    bool operator>(const Date& other) const;
    bool operator<(const Date& other) const;
    bool operator>=(const Date& other) const;
    bool operator<=(const Date& other) const;

    void SetDay(unsigned int day);
    void SetMonth(unsigned int month);
    void SetYear(unsigned int year);
    void SetDate(unsigned int day, unsigned int month, unsigned int year);

    unsigned int GetDay() const;
    unsigned int GetMonth() const;
    unsigned int GetYear() const;

    std::string GetString() const;

private:

    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int year;

    unsigned int GetCombinedDateValue() const;
    static unsigned int GetTotalDaysOfMonth(unsigned int month, unsigned int year);
    static bool IsLeapYear(unsigned int year);
    static bool IsValidDate(unsigned int day, unsigned int month, unsigned int year);
};

#endif // DATE_HPPs
```

### Date.cpp

```
#include "Date.hpp"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

Date::Date() : day(1), month(1), year(0)
{

}

Date::Date(unsigned int day, unsigned int month, unsigned int year) :
    day(day), month(month), year(year)
{
    if (!IsValidDate(this->day, this->month, this->year))
        throw std::invalid_argument(
            "Invalid date values: day=" + std::to_string(this->day)
            + ", month=" + std::to_string(this->month)
            + ", year=" + std::to_string(this->year));
}

Date::Date(const Date& other) :
    day(other.day), month(other.month), year(other.year)
{

}

Date& Date::operator=(const Date& other)
{
    this->day = other.day;
    this->month = other.month;
    this->year = other.year;
    return *this;
}

bool Date::operator==(const Date& other) const
{
    return this->GetCombinedDateValue() == other.GetCombinedDateValue();
}

bool Date::operator!=(const Date& other) const
{
    return !(*this == other);
}

bool Date::operator>(const Date& other) const
{
    return this->GetCombinedDateValue() > other.GetCombinedDateValue();
}

bool Date::operator<(const Date& other) const
{
    return this->GetCombinedDateValue() < other.GetCombinedDateValue();
}

bool Date::operator>=(const Date& other) const
{
    return this->GetCombinedDateValue() >= other.GetCombinedDateValue();
}

bool Date::operator<=(const Date& other) const
{
    return this->GetCombinedDateValue() <= other.GetCombinedDateValue();
}

void Date::SetDay(unsigned int day)
{
    this->day = day;
}

void Date::SetMonth(unsigned int month)
{
    this->month = month;
}

void Date::SetYear(unsigned int year)
{
    this->year = year;
}

void Date::SetDate(unsigned int day, unsigned int month, unsigned int year)
{
    this->day = day;
    this->month = month;
    this->year = year;
}

unsigned int Date::GetDay() const
{
    return this->day;
}

unsigned int Date::GetMonth() const
{
    return this->month;
}

unsigned int Date::GetYear() const
{
    return this->year;
}

std::string Date::GetString() const
{
    return "Date(" + std::to_string(this->day) + ", " + std::to_string(this->month) + ", " + std::to_string(this->year) + ")";
}

unsigned int Date::GetCombinedDateValue() const
{
    /**
     * Priority: year-month-date
     *
     * january 15th 2022 as a combined value: 20220115
     * october 9th 2023 as a combined value: 20231009
     *
     * Comparing example: 20231009 > 20220115 Ok!
     */
    return this->year * 10000 + this->month * 100 + this->day;
}

unsigned int Date::GetTotalDaysOfMonth(unsigned int month, unsigned int year)
{
    static const unsigned int JANUARY = 1;
    static const unsigned int FEBRUARY = 2;
    static const unsigned int MARCH = 3;
    static const unsigned int APRIL = 4;
    static const unsigned int MAY = 5;
    static const unsigned int JUNE = 6;
    static const unsigned int JULY = 7;
    static const unsigned int AUGUST = 8;
    static const unsigned int SEPTEMBER = 9;
    static const unsigned int OCTOBER = 10;
    static const unsigned int NOVEMBER = 11;
    static const unsigned int DECEMBER = 12;

    // February is a special case -> handle it first
    unsigned int day = 0;
    if (month == FEBRUARY)
        day = 28 + ((IsLeapYear(year)) ? 1 : 0);
    else
    {
        switch (month)
        {
        case JANUARY:
        case MARCH:
        case MAY:
        case JULY:
        case AUGUST:
        case OCTOBER:
        case DECEMBER:
            day = 31;
            break;
        case APRIL:
        case JUNE:
        case SEPTEMBER:
        case NOVEMBER:
            day = 30;
            break;
        };
    }
    return day;
}

bool Date::IsLeapYear(unsigned int year)
{
    /**
     * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year :
     *
     *    "Every year that is exactly divisible by four is a leap year, except
     *     for years that are exactly divisible by 100, but these centurial
     *     years are leap years if they are exactly divisible by 400. For
     *     example, the years 1700, 1800, and 1900 are not leap years, but the
     *     years 1600 and 2000 are."
     */

    bool divisableByFour = (year % 4 == 0);
    bool divisableByHundred = (year % 100 == 0);
    bool divisableByFourHundred = (year % 400 == 0);

    if (!divisableByFour)
        return false;
    if (!divisableByHundred) // && divisableByFour
        return true;
    return divisableByFourHundred; // && divisableByFour && divisableByHundred
}

bool Date::IsValidDate(unsigned int day, unsigned int month, unsigned int year)
{
    bool isValid = true;
    isValid = isValid && (month <= 12);
    isValid = isValid && (day <= GetTotalDaysOfMonth(month, year));
    return isValid;
}
```

### Description:

---

I want to create a code that can be used to book certain things. These things is defined with 'referenceID', examples on this would be a cabin, bike or a car (it is only a name so it works with anything).

If it looks like there are missing a main() it is because that one are irrelevant in this situation and I only need some guidence with one function.

In 'Reservation.cpp' there are a function that is named Overlaps (bool Reservation::Overlaps() const). The use of this is to check if there has been an overlap in the booking.

There so called rules for Overlaps() are as followed:

1. It´s end date is not before it´s start date.
2. No other booking exists with the same reference ID for the same period of time. - However, two bookings are allowed to share the same time period if they have different referer IDs.

For example:

```
Reservation foo("Bastuflotta", Date(1, 1, 2022), Date(5, 1, 2022));
Reservation bar("Bastuflotta", Date(3, 1, 2022), Date(8, 1, 2022));

foo.Overlaps(bar); // returns true
```

The following two are not an overlap since they do not share the same reference Id:

```
Reservation foo("Bastuflotta", Date(1, 1, 2022), Date(5, 1, 2022));
Reservation bar("Badtunna", Date(3, 1, 2022), Date(8, 1, 2022));

foo.Overlaps(bar); // returns false
```

I have tried and tried but can't get Overlaps to work. Pls if you have any examples or tips on how to do it, pls share you´r thoughts.

Thank you in beforehand!

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks quite clean, it's nice to see a header and implementation file for each class, and you have gotten `const` and references correct everywhere. There are still some issues though.

## Unnecessary use of `this->`

Your code uses `this->` a lot, however it is often not necessary to write this in C++, and just adds noise. Consider removing it everywhere.

## About your copy constructors and assignment operators

You wrote copy constructors and assignment operators for all your classes, but for some it is not necessary as the compiler will generate these automatically for you, and for some you might want to forbid copy construction/assignment.

For `Reservation` and `Date` you can omit the copy constructors and assignment operators. The compiler will generate exactly the same code for you without you having to do anything. This is also less bug-prone, because if you would add a field to `Reservation` or `Date` and forget to update both the copy constructor and assignment operator, you will have a problem.

For `BookingSystem` there is a better reason to write your own copy constructor and assignment operator, and that is the manual memory management you have to do. The manual stuff could have been avoided (see below), but more importantly you might want to forbid copying `BookingSystem`s altogether. Consider that for assignment, all old reservations will be lost, and for both copy construction and assignment there will now be two copies of the `other`'s reservations. That doesn't sound like a good idea. Consider explicitly deleting them to prevent this from happening:

```
BookingSystem(const BookingSystem& other) = delete;
BookingSystem& operator=(const BookingSystem& other) = delete;
```

## Avoid manual memory management

Calling `new` and `delete` manually is a lot of work and error-prone. While you did a rather good job here, there are still memory leaks possible if exceptions are thrown at some points (consider that `new` can `throw` if it is running out of memory).

Instead of doing this yourself, use [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) from the [standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to handle memory management for you. In particular, use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to store your reservations; it does pretty much exactly what you were doing manually. Here is how it would look:

```
#include <vector>
…
class BookingSystem
{
    std::vector<Reservation> reservations;

public:
    void Reserve(const std::string& referenceID, const Date& start, const Date& end); 

    int GetReservationCount() const;
    const std::vector<Reservation>& GetReservations() const;
};

void BookingSystem::Reserve(const std::string& referenceID, const Date& start, const Date& end)
{
    // Note that this doesn't check for overlap
    reservations.emplace_back(refrenceID, start, end);
}

int BookingSystem::GetReservationCount() const
{
    return reservations.size();
}

const std::vector<Reservation>& BookingSystem::GetReservations() const
{
    return reservations;
}
```

Note that the above will allow copy construction and assignment of `BookingSystem`s, and while it is completely safe from a memory management perspective, you should probably still delete the copy constructor and copy assigment operator. However, move construction and move assignment could be useful, and the compiler can generate default implementations for those if you tell it to:

```
BookingSystem(const BookingSystem& other) = delete;
BookingSystem(BookingSystem&& other) = default;

BookingSystem& operator=(const BookingSystem& other) = delete;
BookingSystem& operator=(BookingSystem&& other) = default;
```

See the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_five).

## Use a time or date type from the standard library

Instead of writing your own `Date` class, consider using a time or date type from the standard library. Watch [The Problem with Time & Timezones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) for why you don't want to implement your own.

I recommend that you either use [`std::chrono::time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) for the start and end of reservations, or if you really want just day granularity and can use C++20, use [`std::chrono::year_month_day`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day).

## Handling overlap

At Code Review we only review working code. It might be better to ask on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) if you have issues getting this to work. In your `Overlaps()` function you never check the start and end date of `other`, that is of course a big problem. I would also only check the dates for overlap, not look at the `referenceID`s; the caller can check separately if the `referenceID`s match, and this will allow it more flexibility in how to handle overlaps.

Even if `Overlaps()` works correctly, there is another issue in `Reserve()`: what should you do if a reservation has overlap? If they are from different `referenceID`s, then you should reject the booking. If they are from the same, you could either store both bookings, or perhaps merge the two bookings into one which covers the dates of both original bookings. Your code doesn't handle that yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will for shure take this and use it next time I am writing something.